# Where do Chrome and Firefox store their "reopen on browser restart" windows/history?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, google-chrome

Recently I have had my Win 7 installation go corrupt.

The good news for me is I put that HDD onto a USB enclosure and I can access all the files in it.

I want to wipe it clean and do a re-install from the beginning but if possible I would like to get all the important data I have on that drive before I do so... and one kind of important part is the browser tabs that reopen when I restart Chrome and Firefox.

Any idea where that is stored?

And finally, same question but for all my bookmarks on Chrome and FF...?

I am/was on Win7 64bit.

Thanks!
Ryan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both firefox and chrome store bookmarks and tabs data in their respective profile directories, their locations are as below:

For firefox:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
```

For chrome:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

Backup and replicate these folders in the same location on your new installation to restore you profiles. Hope this helps.